# c++ libnoise error to Perlin

Tags: c++, perlin-noise

i installed libnoise on windows with code::blocks

and at compiling it gives an error:

```
undefined reference to `noise::module::Perlin::Perlin()'
undefined reference to `noise::module::Perlin::GetValue(double, double, double) const'
undefined reference to `vtable for noise::module::Perlin'
undefined reference to `noise::module::Module::~Module()'
```

but the references are in the `perlin.h` header file

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Looks like you need to link the libnoise DLL.

Comment: Look it up in your compiler's documentation.

Comment: Dont find out anything. Im using MingW and Code::Blocks, please give a hint

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, **libnoise** comes with a *.def file which takes care of exporting symbols. But as I tried to compile the lib in 64 bit this morning, it appeared that this mechanism did not work.
I had to "manually" export class symbols :

Steps to export libnoise symbols :

. Define a preprocessor variable `LIBNOISE_EXPORT` when compiling the lib as a shared library, do not add it when compiling a project that *uses* the lib

. Add some export macros in a top-level header of the lib (basictypes.h for example):

```
#if defined(WIN32)
#   ifdef LIBNOISE_EXPORT
#       define LIBNOISE_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define LIBNOISE_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#   define LIBNOISE_DLL
#endif
```

. Add the LIBNOISE_DLL macro in front of class definition :

```
class LIBNOISE_DLL Perlin: public Module
{
   ...
```

And that did the trick for me

note : do not use the *.def file in your compilation process if you try this solution